# Can a PPT macro invoked automatically when file is saved?

Tags: vba, save, powerpoint

I have a macro for a PowerPoint deck that creates a set of dashboard slides. The dashboard is a table with data from each slide on a separate row, including the slide number, so it is a sort of table of contents.

Many people update this deck and change the slide order.

Is there a way to have this macro run automatically when a person hits the save button? or can I add a button to the file so a person can click it to run the macro?

Thanks!
Carolyn

Comment: `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.application.presentationbeforesave`

Comment: Yes, that's possible by creating class modules that capture events. Here's an introductory article, check out the links as well: http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00004_Make_your_VBA_code_in_PowerPoint_respond_to_events.htm

Comment: I have been trying to make this work but I am not sure what to do regarding this note:
An Event handler cannot be set automatically. To set an event handler when PowerPoint starts up you still need to rely on the Auto_Open macro of an add-in to instantiate the event handler.

how do I set this up so that anyone who opens the file will automatically have the event handler turned on?

Comment: Look at the beforesave event, is this a "custom" save button or saving the pres?